# Sending images using i2c

Tags: image, send, i2c, data-transfer, communication-protocol

I have a question. I would like to know if it is possible to send images from one device to another using I2C communication.

Someone can help me, please?

I am actually using a camera with a WiFi module to transfer data, but I need to separate the photo capture and transmission to do it with 2 devices to reduction size of capturing device. So, I am searching how send the data saved in a SD card in one device to another device and that's the reason to asking if it is possible to send images through I2C.

Comment: Yes, but It will be way too slow, basically makes your idea not to fly. I suggest don't even try. SPI is what you may consider instead.

Comment: The easiest to use will probably be RS-232. Still not super-fast, but very easy to use.

Comment: @PMF, the [standard] UART is not even close to the speed of I2C. In any case, it is quite likely somewhat 4Mbps vs. 3.4Mbps on modern hardware. Moreover, UART needs additional wires to have a flow control.